# Dependency conflict in integrating with Cloudera Hbase 1.0.0

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, hbase

I tried to connect my play framework (2.4.2) web application to a cloudera hbase cluster. I included hbase dependencies in my bulid.sbt file and used hbase sample code to insert a cell into a table. However, I got this exception which seems to be dependency conflict between play framework and Hbase.
I also attached my sample code and build.sbt files as well. I would be grateful for your help to resolve this error.

```
    [ERROR] [07/21/2015 12:03:05.919] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [ActorSystem(application)] Uncaught fatal error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down ActorSystem [application]
    java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:434)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1262)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.flush(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1496)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:1107)
        at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:44)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:95)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:95)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:127)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:70)
        at play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$1.call(DefaultHttpRequestHandler.java:20)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

this is my bulid.sbt file:

```
name := """HbaseTest"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
//hbase
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.0.0-cdh5.4.4" 
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-annotations" % "1.0.0-cdh5.4.4" 
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.0.0-cdh5.4.4"
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-protocol" % "1.0.0-cdh5.4.4" 
//hadoop
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common"%"2.6.0-cdh5.4.4" 
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-annotations"%"2.6.0-cdh5.4.4" 
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-auth"%"2.6.0-cdh5.4.4"
// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

this is my code:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.compress.Compression.Algorithm;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {       
          String ZooKeeperIP = "10.12.7.43";
          String ZooKeeperPort = "2181";
          String HBaseMaster = "10.12.7.43:60000";
          Configuration hBaseConfig;
          Connection  connection = null;
          //TableName TABLE_NAME = "sample";
          hBaseConfig =  HBaseConfiguration.create();
            hBaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",ZooKeeperIP);
            hBaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", ZooKeeperPort);
            hBaseConfig.set("hbase.master", HBaseMaster);


            //connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hBaseConfig);

            try {
                connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hBaseConfig);
                HTable table = new HTable(hBaseConfig, "sample");
                Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("1"));
                p.add(Bytes.toBytes("a"), Bytes.toBytes("b"), Bytes.toBytes("4"));
                table.put(p);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());         
            }
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I can see, The trouble is with the dependencies.
Specifically `guava` library (which is a common problem with `hadoop`).
`Play` uses newer version of `guava` as I can see. It doesn't have the `StopWatch` class which `hbase` requires.

You could approach the problem this is in multiple ways (All of them I know are 'hacky' unfortunately).

Easy way is to use a hack like [`zipkin`](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-hbase/src/test/guava-hack/src/main/java/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.java). Where we would add the `StopWatch` ourselves.

Another way would be to somehow separate HBase operations. (Which would require lot of work and design changes)

It would have been much easier if `sbt` supported 'shading', As I know it doesn't yet.
You could still workaround it using `sbt` with some effort like how [`spark`](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/1813/files) deals with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I have  spring, hadoop and hbase in one project. I was able to solve this issue by adding explicitly guava lib to my pom.xml. The version must be less then 17  (I've useed 16.0.1)

I've got more info on this place:
https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1236