# TemporaryBackendException while using JanusGraph Java API and HBase

Tags: java, hbase, janusgraph

I am using JanusGraph Java API, with HBase as storage backend

One thing I have to mention is that I can successfully run the same commands in JanusGraph shell, `gremlin.sh`

The log before the error is below, which happens during the opening of the graph instance, `JanusGraphFactory.open(jg.properties)`

```
07:20:46.169 [main-SendThread(cdh-master1:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - 
Reading reply sessionid:0x263f89ba9d56ce2, 
packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 3,8  replyHeader:: 3,55834924519,0  
request:: '/hbase,F  response:: v{'replication,'meta-region-server,'rs,'splitWAL,'backup-masters,
'table-lock,'flush-table-proc,'region-in-transition,'online-snapshot,'master,'running,'recovering-regions,'draining,'namespace,'hbaseid,'table} 
07:20:46.182 [main] WARN  o.j.d.hbase.HBaseStoreManager - Unexpected exception during getDeployment()
```

and the error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:364) ~[jar:rsrc:janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getFeatures(HBaseStoreManager.java:403) ~[jar:rsrc:janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1377) [jar:rsrc:janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:164) [jar:rsrc:janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:133) [jar:rsrc:janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:80) [jar:rsrc:janusgraph-core-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
```

I have no idea with this `TemporaryBackendException`, has anyone met this before?

part of the janusgraph config is

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
cluster.max-partitions=64
storage.backend=hbase
storage.batch-loading=true
storage.hostname=cdh-master1,cdh-master2,cdh-master3
```

where `cdh-master1,2,3` are zookeeper quorum, version JanusGraph 2.0, HBase 1.2

The full stack trace is

```
at my.graph.Graph.<clinit>(Graph.java:7) [rsrc:./:na]
at my.graph.App.main(App.java:24) [rsrc:./:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58) [janus.jar:na]
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:739) ~[jar:rsrc:janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getLocalKeyPartition(HBaseStoreManager.java:524) ~[jar:rsrc:janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:361) ~[jar:rsrc:janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.translateException(RpcRetryingCaller.java:229) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:202) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:821) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:303) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseAdmin1_0.tableExists(HBaseAdmin1_0.java:111) ~[jar:rsrc:janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:716) ~[jar:rsrc:janusgraph-hbase-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:596) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:580) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:559) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1185) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1152) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:300) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:151) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200) ~[jar:rsrc:hbase-client-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
... 24 common frames omitted
```

part of my `pom.mxl` including the dependency information is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>janusgraph-hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: please post the full stack trace so we can see the root cause

Comment: @JasonPlurad added, this is the stack trace following the origin error

Comment: Looks like a Guava conflict that you'd need to resolve. Are you using Maven, Gradle, or some other tool for dependency management? If so, could you post your build deps file?

Comment: @JasonPlurad I am using Maven, updated my dependencies in `pom.xml`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725234/connecting-to-remote-hbase-service-using-java - the important error here is `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted an answer [here](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1156#issuecomment-405032222) previously:

This is a Guava version conflict issue. The JanusGraph [HBase example](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.2.0/janusgraph-examples/example-hbase/pom.xml#L22-L33) does not run into a Guava version error because of its specific dependencies listed and the order of those dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>janusgraph-hbase</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-shaded-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase100.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Note the usage of `hbase-shaded-client` (fixed with [Issue #512](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/512)) rather than `hbase-client` in your `pom.xml` which has a shaded version of Guava for use with HBase. Shading renames the package names of some of the dependencies, and this allows you to have different versions of Guava on the classpath without causing conflicts.

The Gremlin Console uses the `hbase-shaded-client` also and you can find that jar in the `lib` directory of the distribution.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly a Guava conflict and the `hbase-shaded-client` could avoid this conflict. I forgot this question, sorry for the delay of acceptance